# Get value form text box using id in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

For testing i want to check console what is the value set fro the text box but other than IE Working fine but IE 10 not able to get value.

```
$('#refno').getval;
document.getelementById("refno").value;
```

[image]

Comment: is it not "getElementById"? ('E' caps)

Comment: Hard to belive either of your examples to work in any browser...

Comment: @Teemu, they wouldn't because they both are incorrect!

Comment: @LShetty I know, but OP says they work in other browsers than IE...

Comment: i try $('#id').val() but  it print like this in console              >> $('#OUTPUT_REF_NO').val;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE 10 try this

### Go to current window

> > cd()
> >     Current window: app.jsp

### set mainframe go to the main page having component

> > cd(mainframe) 
> >     Current window: sb.jsp

### for get vale usind id

> > $('#comtype').val() 
> >     "6"

Answer (score 1):

use val() in jquery

```
  $('#refno').val();
```

in javscript

```
document.getElementById("refno").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method name is **[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)**, not `document.getelementById` (Notice the difference between `Element` and `element`), so you can change:

```
document.getelementById("refno").value;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("refno").value;
```

in jQuery, you can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of `getval`:

```
$('#refno').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mis-spelled the function you are using to get the elements. You need `val()` intead of `getval`, also you need `getElementById` instead of `getelementById` as javascript is case sensitive.

```
$('#refno').val()
```

*OR*

```
$('#refno')[0].value
```

Comment: if i try $('#refno')[0].value this                                                 It is saying unable to get properity 'value'  of undefiend or null reference

Comment: It means you did not get the object, show me the html you have and where you have this javascript, making a demo on jsfiddle would be great

Comment: <input type="text" name="emailId" data-label="Business Email ID" data-mandatory="Y" id="emailId" class="valid" data-spine-prop="emailId" data-spine-type="text" value="" size="30" data-rule-required="true">

Comment: This html does not have element with id refno

Comment: that is different element any text box same issue.

Comment: what about using $('#refno').get(0).value

Comment: that also not working in IE 10   error-> unable to get proparity 'value'  of undefined or null reference